# Flutter Windows App does not start in release mode

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I just created a flutter project on Windows with

```
flutter create appname --platforms=windows,macos
```

Now I can start this Windows app with

```
flutter run -d windows
```

and everything works perfectly.
But the problem is that I can not start the Windows app in release mode. I tried:

```
flutter run --release -d windows
```

but the app window is not showing up. I just see the process running in the task manager. There is no need to show you the code of the project as it is the template project you get with `flutter create`. No single line was modified.

The release mode works on every other platforms including web and macos. I also tried to start the `.exe` file manually but that doesn't work either. I also tried changing to the master version of flutter but it also does not work with the latest master version.

`flutter doctor -v` does not show any errors:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.9.0-17.0.pre.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.9.0-17.0.pre.7 on channel master at C:\Program Files\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 785ea2a4c9 (2 hours ago), 2023-03-24 13:01:07 -0400
    • Engine revision 7b91f9d08f
    • Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-365.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.22.2

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33516.290
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2
    • Flutter plugin version 58.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 211.7665

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.111
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.51

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you edit the `windows/runner/flutter_window.cpp` like mentioned in [@Zensonaton's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15227244/zensonaton) answer. But I fixed it by adding a `restorationScopeId` in `MaterialApp` like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      restorationScopeId: "Test", // <-- Add this line
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug with Flutter?

Edit the `windows/runner/flutter_window.cpp`, replace this line:

```cpp
flutter_controller_->engine()->SetNextFrameCallback([&]() {
    this->Show();
});
```

with this:

```cpp
this->Show();
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119415#issuecomment-1443257156).